# Prevent bootstrap accordion from openning when clicking on a button on header

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have two action buttons that are situated on the header of an a accordion like this :

[image]

When I click on one of these buttons, it toggles the state of the accordion, I tried `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` with no results

Here's the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bxzhqsad/3/

Keep in mind that I'm using Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting elements inside the .accordion-button won't allow to capture the inner elements events. A way to achieve this functionality is to separate the inner buttons alongside the .accordion-button and then with absolute positioning achieve a visually similar appearance:

```
<h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-heading-1">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <button type="button" class="accordion-button collapsed text-start" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#item_1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="#item_1">
        <h5 class="content_title fw-bold w-100 text-left">Title 1</h5>
      </button>
      <div class="d-flex align-items-start position-fixed" style="right:100px; z-index:1000;">
          <span class="fa fa-pencil-alt cercle-icons edit-icon" data-app-id="1" data-content-id="1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="far fa-trash-alt cercle-icons delete-icon" data-app-id="1" data-content-id="1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</h2>
```

Please see [the modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zan8pxkt/2/)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to solve it:

The accordion button has the following data attribute

```
data-bs-collapse="collapse"
```

Without it, the accordion won't work. So, we can use that as a trick to disable the accordion when the mouse is over our own button.

basically saying:

on ***mouseenter*** event of your button, set the accordion button `data-bs-collapse` to empty string `""`

on ***mouseleave*** event of your button, set the accordion button `data-bs-collapse` back to `"collapse"`

I will assume your button is a direct child of the collapse button/div, so here is some code:

```
yourButton.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
  let accordionButton = yourButton.parentElement;
  accordionButton.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle', '');
});

yourButton.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
  let accordionButton = yourButton.parentElement;
  accordionButton.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle', 'collapse');
});

yourButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // do whatever you want...
});
```

Hope this help!