# How to add buttons on the header of a Bootstrap Accordion in such a way that clicking it won't collapse or expand it?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Here I added 2 buttons on the header of the Accordion, but when I click the button, the entire Accordion collapses or expands. Is there a way to add buttons to it in such a way that clicking them won't collapse or expand the Accordion?

```html
<div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo">
            <div>26-08-21</div>
            <div style="margin-left: -20px;" class="col-1"></div>
            <div>project_id</div>
            <div class="col-3"></div>
            <div>title</div>
            <div class="col-3"></div>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm  btn-success">
            <em class="far fa-edit"></em>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit
        </button>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete
        </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse"
        aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
        <div class="accordion-body">
            <br>
            <button style="margin-left: 20px;" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">Download CSV</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent accordion from toggling when button in header is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469602/how-to-prevent-accordion-from-toggling-when-button-in-header-is-clicked)

Answer (score -1):

With the on click of buttons, you need to use `$event.stopPropagation()`

```
public onButtonClick($event): void {
    // Do something on click
    $event.stopPropagation()
}
```

Comment: sorry i added the code to ts file of that angular component and linked it to click event on button but still the same

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, but you can find the same solution with a demo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24469635) (on a duplicate question)

Comment: Though since the other solution I mentioned was for bootstrap 3 and for a panel-collapse combination, it might not work for an accordion in bootstrap 5. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67342643/prevent-bootstrap-accordion-from-openning-when-clicking-on-a-button-on-header) is tackling the same issue and there are only two rather hacky solutions.