# In Bootstrap V5, How to prevent accordion from toggling when element in header is clicked?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I know in bootstrap v4 we can use `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent accordion from toggling when element in header is clicked.

Like this question.

[How to prevent accordion from toggling when button in header is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469602/how-to-prevent-accordion-from-toggling-when-button-in-header-is-clicked)

However, this method seems not working in Bootstrap v5.

Here is the example.

https://jsfiddle.net/8qdbjfx2/4/

Curious about how to do it?

Thanks for yours answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you've solved your problem but I found one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67342643/prevent-bootstrap-accordion-from-openning-when-clicking-on-a-button-on-header).

Based on that I created a [simpler example](https://codepen.io/filipescaglia/pen/xxLMard):

```html
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="content_accordion">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-heading-1">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center position-relative">
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="accordion-button collapsed"
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#item_1"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="#item_1"
                >
                    Title 1
                </button>
                <div class="header-slot">
                    <i class="bi bi-pencil-fill" onclick="hello()"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h2>
        <div id="item_1" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-heading-1" data-bs-parent="#content_accordion">
            <div class="accordion-body content_text">Content 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't solved this problem yet. Using Absolute is a way, I will try to implement this. But I more want to why I can't use `e.stopPropagation();` in this case.

Comment: I can do what I want to do by following this answer. Thank you.